# setting adapter gives null exception in retrofit 2 call back method?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am new to android and I have been using retrofit 2 to get data from the server, in my app when activity starts or on create of activity, a method is called to fetch data from server and on-Response of this call I am getting data and setting the data to the spinner and it gets successful and the list of data is visible in user interface when running the app.
Now I have to add Autocomplete text-view so that on typing a character the spinner gives that list of data according to the typed characters in Autocomplete text-view.
I have added array adapter with data and I set it to the spinner it works, below this using same array adapter I set it to the Autocomplete text-view but gives an error of null pointer exception. So for my understanding adapter is somehow setting it early which points to the null error.

```
 public void fetch_information() {
    ApiInterface2 = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);

    Call<List<City>> call = ApiInterface2.GetCities();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<City>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<City>> call, Response<List<City>> response) {
            CityList = new ArrayList<City>();
            CityList = response.body();
            City myCustomObject = new City();
            myCustomObject.setCityName("Select Country");
            CityList.add(myCustomObject);
            ArrayList<String> CityNames = new ArrayList<String>();



            cities = new String[CityList.size()];
            citiesid = new String[CityList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < CityList.size(); i++) {
                cities[i] = CityList.get(i).getCityName();
                citiesid[i] = CityList.get(i).getCityId();
                 CityNames.add(CityList.get(i).getCityName());

            }

            city_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddKhataPurchase.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities);
            city_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_layout);
            city_spinner.setAdapter(city_adapter);
            city_spinner.setSelection(cities.length - 1);

          //  fetch_searchable_spinner_cities();
            if(CityNames.size()> 1) {
                ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddKhataPurchase.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CityNames);

//here not able to set the adapter as null pointer exception happens

                myAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            }
}


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<City>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Activity opens, the method (fetch_information) gets called and here onResponse city spinner after setting array adapter shows the list of cities in UI but when i try to do the same below it by setting array adapter to myAutoCompleteTextview null pointer exception although got the data but still error.
Can i set Autocomplete Textview after the response call finishes?

Comment: post your error logs and whole activity code

Comment: i think the code is fine here the problem was activity layout which i copied from previous and had same ids for most of my widget so no issues were found up till now that is why when i add newly auto complete text view it was not visible to the screen which was showing same layout of the previous and also the id was not present in previous layout that why i was getting null pointer exception on the first place.After changing the layout to original where i was working it starts to show UI